# How can I save the result of my query as a list?

Tags: c#

I try to get a documents from a file, which 2 dates contain (FromDate and To date). How can I save the result of my query as a list? Thank you for help!

```
    public static IEnumerable<String> GetModificationFilesBetweenDates(String searchPath, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {


        IEnumerable<String> select = (from file in GetAllFilesInPath(searchPath)
                                   where file.ScriptType == SQLFileType.Create
                                   && file.FromDate >= fromDate
                                   && file.ToDate <= toDate
                                   select file.FileName);
        return select;



    }
```

Comment: Do you mean running `ToList()` on it?

Comment: Question is not very clear but if u want to save the list u can save it in XML file.

Comment: File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", GetModificationFilesBetweenDates(...))

Comment: What *exactly* is your question? "Save" "as a list"...? Do you want to output your results to a file? Output to a `List<T>`? Please clarify this in your question

Comment: I've tried with ToList(), but because of IEnumerable<String> it doesn't work.

Comment: exyctly, I want to output the query result as a List<T>

Comment: Do you want to save the result to a file or transform it to a `IList<T>`.

Comment: I want to transform the result to a IList<T>

Comment: It's because you're declaring the `select` as `IEnumerable<string>` that you can't `ToList()` it. Just use `var select = (...).ToList()`, or declare it as `List<string> select = (...).ToList()`

Comment: with var select = (...).ToList() or  List<string> select = (...)   still not working :(

Comment: What does _"still not working"_ mean?  Are you getting an exception?  Compile error?  Give us specific details!

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the `ToList<T>()` extension method of the `System.Linq` namespace:

```
    public static IList<String> GetModificationFilesBetweenDates(String searchPath, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {


        IEnumerable<String> select = (from file in GetAllFilesInPath(searchPath)
                                      where file.ScriptType == SQLFileType.Create
                                      && file.FromDate >= fromDate
                                      && file.ToDate <= toDate
                                      select file.FileName);
        return select.ToList();
    }
```